# Getting an element by class added with addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a class with `addClass()` to an element the user clicked on with

```
$('.question').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).next('.answer').siblings('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.question').removeClass('open');
});
```

This works fine. But now I will get the element with `class="open"` in order to `slideUp()` the answer below. But I can't get it to work. I tried

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

and

```
$('.open').on('click' function() {
    $(this).next('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: event delegattion is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the class dynamically, you need to use event delegation for binding click

```
$(dodcument).on('click','.open', function() {
    $(this).next('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Now the `.answer` element slides up after it slided down immediately. I don't need to click on `.open`.

Comment: I solved my problem by using `.toggleSlide()` method of jQuery.

Comment: Anyway my answer did help you right???? Without event delegation , your code wont work